# Typescript break vs return behavior in recursive function

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

Below are two Typescript functions used to [recursively walk a source file's abstract syntax tree (AST)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker). I have managed to identify the problem that caused my program to only visit part of the tree, but I do not understand *why* the solution works.

The `walkTree1` function is the valid solution that walks the entire tree. The `walkTree2` function only visits part of the tree. The two functions differ only by one line (marked with comment), and obviously the `return` behavior ties into this somehow, but I didn't find anything useful online.

```
function walkTree1(firstNode: ts.SourceFile, visitor: (node: ts.Node) => void): void {
  visitInterfacesRecursive(firstNode);

  function visitInterfacesRecursive(node: ts.Node): void {
    switch (node.kind) {
      case ts.SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration:
        visitor(node); break; // correct
      default:
        ts.forEachChild(node, visitInterfacesRecursive);
    }
  }
}

function walkTree2(firstNode: ts.SourceFile, visitor: (node: ts.Node) => void): void {
  visitInterfacesRecursive(firstNode);

  function visitInterfacesRecursive(node: ts.Node): void {
    switch (node.kind) {
      case ts.SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration:
        return visitor(node); // offending change
      default:
        ts.forEachChild(node, visitInterfacesRecursive);
    }
  }
}
```

At long last, I am stumped. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I have inspected the generated source and there doesn't seem to be any surprises there (no real difference except type erasure). For now I'm posting the original code; if necessary I'll put together something more reproducible when I get home later.

Additional details:

- `node -v` : v8.5.0
- `tsc -v` : Version 2.3.4
- [`ts.forEachChild` source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.3.4/src/compiler/parser.ts#L53)

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). (This will require removing type annotations, but that's just about all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `ts.forEachChild()` doesn't actually run over each child in all cases.  From the linked [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.3.4/src/compiler/parser.ts#L49):

```
// Invokes a callback for each child of the given node. The 'cbNode' callback is invoked for all child nodes
// stored in properties. If a 'cbNodes' callback is specified, it is invoked for embedded arrays; otherwise,
// embedded arrays are flattened and the 'cbNode' callback is invoked for each element. If a callback returns
// a truthy value, iteration stops and that value is returned. Otherwise, undefined is returned.
```

So since you are returning `visitor(node)`, it must sometimes be truthy.  That can presumably happen at runtime even though you have declared `visitor()` as a `void`-returning function, I guess?  (You've left out the particular `visitor()` you used, so I'm not sure)  Since you don't care about the return value of `visitor()` it's best not to return it from `visitInterfacesRecursive()`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I simply did not expect this behavior from a function called `forEach*` (rather than, say, `forSome*`).

Answer (score 2):

The only difference that change makes is to make `visitInterfacesRecursive` return the result of calling `visitor(node)` (in `walkTree2`), whereas in `walkTree1` `visitInterfacesRecursive` reliably returns `undefined`.*

Whatever is calling `visitInterfacesRecursive` is clearly looking at its return value. In `walkTree1`, that return value is reliably `undefined`. In `walkTree2`, it's sometimes `undefined`, and other times whatever `visitor(node)` returns. It would appear that `visitor(node)` returns something other than `undefined` (at least sometimes) and that whatever is looking at the return value of `visitInterfacesRecursive` is interpreting that non-`undefined` return value to mean "stop."

---

* "reliably returns `undefined`" - Technically, the ECMAScript spec makes a distinction between a function that doesn't use `return` at all and one that uses `return` or `return undefined`, but the distinction it makes is not observable in our code. Calling the function gives the same result in all three cases.

Comment: @apk: No, the only call isn't in `walkTree`: You're passing `visitInterfacesRecursive` into `forEachChild`. Clearly, `forEachChild` is using the return value from `visitInterfacesRecursive`.